# Не выполняется переход по ссылке js

Tags: javascript, php

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть код:

```
<?php
echo "<a style='font-size: 14px;color: #777777;' id='kurl' href='javascript: goToPage();'><i class='fas fa-trash-alt'></i></a>
    <script type= 'text/javascript'>
function goToPage()
{
    var url = document.getElementById('kurl');
    document.location.href = '/fun/awd.php/?id='".$row['id_c_t']."'&id_t='".$_GET['id']."';
}
</script>";
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

параметры в ссылке не нужно брать в кавычки, т.е.:

```
document.location.href = '/fun/awd.php/?id=".$row['id_c_t']."&id_t=".$_GET['id']."';
```

Comment: @ВладиславСамохин если это весь Ваш код в `echo`, то перед `echo` сделайте `var_dump($row)` и посмотрите значение `id_c_t`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var url = document.getElementById('kurl');
url.addEventListener('click', goToPage);

function goToPage() {
    document.location.href = 'https://www.google.ru/';
}
```

```html
<a style='font-size: 14px;color: #777777;' id='kurl' href='#'>link<i class='fas fa-trash-alt'></i></a>
```

Comment: Не работает, дело в кавычках в ссылке